# What does ISPAC stands for (in SSIS)

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Can anyone tell what **ISPAC** stands for (in SSIS) please. Today a junior DBA asked me this question, which I attempted to find out, googled it, looked through [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff952821(v=sql.105).aspx) etc. to no avail.

It's the Integration Services project deployment file (with `.ispac` extension) that I'm referring to, which contains SSIS project's metadata.

TIA

Comment: I would assume it's "**I**ntegration **S**ervices **PAC**kage", but why do you care?

Comment: Yes, the "pac" is for "package". Cut from the same tree as DACPAC and BACPAC, which came earlier.

Comment: Thanks both, makes sense. I wasn't sure whether "PAC" is an acronym / abbreviation of something.

Comment: DAC is probably an acronym (though MS will now call the things installed by DACPACs "data-tier applications", which sure doesn't abbreviate that way). Then someone saw "DAC package" and named it DACPAC rather than DACPACK because, well, esthetics. And because it makes the BACPAC pun work. (Confusingly, DAC was already in use for the [dedicated admin connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/diagnostic-connection-for-database-administrators) -- probably no relation.)

Comment: Thanks Jeroen,  good point.

Answer (score 0):

Just see it as entire SSIS project (including project level parameters and connections) **packed** into a zip archive.

Perhaps it is handy for DevOps tasks and automation.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, "PAC" (in ISPAC) is neither an acronym nor an abbreviation of something, it's just a short-form of "Package", therefore I guess this file-extension can be written as "ISPac" (i.e. "**I**ntegration **S**ervices **PAC**kage" (as commented by DavidG).